# Isolating a variable that appears twice on one side of the equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to isolate P in the following equation:

$$ A = se \times P + ( 1 - sp ) \times (1 - P) $$

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Of course:

$$A=se\cdot P + 1-P - sp + sp\cdot P\\
A-1+sp = P(se-1+sp)$$